# Optimization problem with non linear objective and non linear constraint (or upper bounding)

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am tackling the following optimization problem where ideally I would like to maximize (analytically, over $\alpha$) these sorts of quantities, where $n \ll d$ and $d \in \mathbb{N}, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+*}$, and in practice a non trivial upper bound on the objective would be enough.

$$\Gamma(d, n, \alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^{d} \alpha_i^2 e^{- n \alpha_i}$$

Subject to the following constraints,

$$\alpha \in \Delta^{d-1} \text{ (simplex)}$$
$$||\alpha - (1/d)||_1 \geq \epsilon$$

I have a 'hunch' candidate minimizer, an alternating $\alpha_i = (1\pm \epsilon)/d$.

Here is an attempt, but there are a few issues, as I am not sure how to deal with the non-linear constraint, and I cannot rule out some of the cases, where some of the $\alpha_i$ would be larger than $2/n$ (I think I should be able to do that as I am only interested in the limit case $n/d \rightarrow 0$).

Denote $f(\alpha_i)= \alpha_i^2 e^{-n \alpha_i}$. We start by developing a concave upper bound for $f(\alpha_i)$, defined by a second degree polynomial $Q(\alpha_i)$ on $[0, 2/n]$, and a constant piece on $[2/n, 1]$. We wish $Q$ to satisfy the following equalities,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Q(0) &= 0 \\
Q(2/n) &= 4/n^2 \\
Q'(2/n) &= 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Which yields the following $g$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g(\alpha_i) = \begin{cases}
             \alpha_i(4/n - \alpha_i)  & \text{if } \alpha_i \in [0, 2/n] \\
             4/n^2 & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

It follows that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Gamma(d, n, \alpha) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{d} g(\alpha_i)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Using Lagrange multipliers,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}(d, n, \alpha, \lambda, \mu) = \sum_{i=1}^{d} g(\alpha_i) - \lambda \left( \sum_{i=1}^{d} \alpha_i - 1 \right) - \mu \left( \sum_{i=1}^{d} |\alpha_i - 1/d| - \epsilon \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

$\forall k \in [d]$,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \alpha_k} &= g'(\alpha_k) - \lambda = \begin{cases}
             (4/n - 2 \alpha_k) - \lambda - \mu sgn(\alpha_k - 1/d) & \text{if } \alpha_k \in [0, 2/n] \\
             - \lambda - \mu sgn(\alpha_k - 1/d) & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases} \\
\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial \alpha_k^2} &= g''(\alpha_k) = \begin{cases}
             -2  & \text{if } \alpha_k \in [0, 2/n] \\
             0 & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases} \\ \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We wish to solve $\forall k \in [d], \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \alpha_k} = 0$.

Take $\alpha_k < 1/d$, then since $d \gg n$, $\alpha_k < 1/n$, $sgn(\alpha_i - 1/d) = -1$, and

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\alpha_k = \frac{2}{n} - \frac{\lambda - \mu}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

meaning that all $\alpha_k$ strictly smaller than $1/d$ are equal: $\exists \alpha^-, \forall k \in [d], \alpha_k < 1/d \Rightarrow \alpha_k = \alpha^-$.

Take now $\alpha_k > 1/d$, if $\lambda + \mu = 0$, then all $\alpha_k$ are large: $\alpha_k > 2/n$ (but not necessarily the same...). If $\lambda + \mu \neq 0$, then the solution to $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \alpha_k} = 0$ must be for $\alpha_k \in [0, 2/n]$ on which $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \alpha_k}$ is strictly decreasing. Hence $\alpha_k = \alpha^{+} < 2/n$.

I am not able to rule out the possibility that some of the $\alpha_i = 1/d$.

Suppose I managed to rule out unwanted cases and have two possible values for the $\alpha_i$, then it becomes easy

Denote by 
$$I^+ = \{ k \in [d], \alpha_k > 1/d \}, I^- = \{ k \in [d], \alpha_k < 1/d \}$$
$$d^+ = |I^+|, d^- = |I^-|$$

It immediately follows that
\begin{equation} \label{eq:sum}
\begin{split}
d &= d^+ + d^- 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:simplex}
\begin{split}
d^-\alpha^- + d^+\alpha^+ = 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Setting $||\alpha - (1/d)||_1 = \epsilon$, also

\begin{equation} \label{eq:precision}
\begin{split}
d^+\alpha^+ - d^-\alpha^- + \frac{1}{d}(d^- - d^+) = \epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and from the above, it follows that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split} \label{eq:weights}
\alpha^+ &= \frac{1}{d} + \frac{\epsilon}{2d^+} \\
\alpha^- &= \frac{1}{d} - \frac{\epsilon}{2d^-}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The objective function can then be rewritten as a function of $d^+/d$ whose optimal value $1/2$ can be found, and an upper bound can then be obtained by plugging in.

Comment: By the method of Lagrange multipliers I think you get that all $\alpha_i>1/d$ have the same value and all $\alpha_i<1/d$ have the same value. Fixing how many coordinates are in each of the cases fixes those values. It remains to optimize over these counts.

Comment: What is $\Delta$?

Comment: @PaataIvanisvili I understood it to be the simplex $\{\alpha:\alpha_i\ge 0, \sum_i\alpha_i = 1\}$. I think $n$ in $\Delta^{n-1}$ is meant to be $d$.

Comment: You are right there was a typo, and delta is meant to be the simplex. Thank you for the outline Yoav Kallus

Comment: @YoavKallus . Made an attempt following your outline, but I have trouble ruling out some of the possible cases and using the Lagrangian with the L1 norm.